# Django Dynamically Calculate Average

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I've multiple fields in my model, and I need to remove the average of only the columns user inputs
Could be

How can I do it dynamically?

I know I can do

```
mean = results.aggregate(Avg("student_score"))
```

This is one, I want to add multiple Avg statements dynamically

I tried making a loop as well to get all names and add all fields given by user one by one

eg - Avg('students'), Avg('playtime'), Avg('grade'), Avg('sales')

But I get

```
QuerySet.aggregate() received non-expression(s): <class 'django.db.models.aggregates.Avg'>('students'), <class 'django.db.models.aggregates.Avg'>('sales').
```

I've even tried raw query, but it needs a unique ID because of which that isn't working
Any workaround ideas?

I am using MySQL DB

Comment: Please share your code where you do the average calculation and your model.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate return single result from the list of objects. You need to annotate if you need multiple result like following,

```
YourModel.objects.values("YOUR GROUP BY VALUES HERE").annotate(Avg('students'), Avg('playtime'), Avg('grade'), Avg('sales')
```